# Running on IDE vs Running by .exe

Tags: c#, oracle

**THIS IS THE CODE**

```
using System;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.Text;

namespace Insert
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(String[] args) 
        {
            String param = "1";
            if (args.Length > 0)
            {
                param = args[0];
            }
            String connString = "User Id=****;Password=*******;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=*********)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=orcl))); Connection Timeout=5";

            using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();

                cmd.CommandText = String.Format("INSERT INTO PROCESS_TEST ( SEQ, TEST ) VALUES ( TEST_SEQ.nextval, '{0}' )", param);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, **it's very simple C# code**.

All it has to do is to connect to the database and insert a string data ( default will be "1" )........... Well I know it could be messy far under the connection work with `Oracle.DataAccess.Client` But I don't think it's so heavy library that it makes such a difference in app performance.

---

**Running on IDE ( Visual Studio 2013 for my case )**

- Blazing fast like a blink of an eye, it takes less than a sec.

**Running by .exe**

- ***Tooooooooo slow*** to call it a simple application. It takes approximately 3 to 5 minitues.
- This process is finished after 3-5 minutes. I put logs on every steps of the code and I noticed that `using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(connString))` is the main reason.

**Memory**

[image]

And I don't understand why it takes up more than 40MB memory to execute the process. Do any other data access libraries take up the similar amount of memory like that??

---

**QUESTIONS**

1. What's the difference between running an app on IDE and by `.exe?`
2. Why does my app take so long to finish its job when run by `.exe`?
3. Why is there such a huge performance difference?
4. Is it a known `Oracle.DataAccess` library issue?

---

**ENVIRONMENT INFO**

- Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz
- 8.00GB RAM
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle has had similar issues in the past with a logging directory not existing. [This blog post](http://www.geoffhudik.com/tech/2011/8/19/slow-oracleconnection-creation.html) may help you.

Comment: From the comment there that mention similar symptom (fast when debugging) it appears the logging logic is skipped or modified when it's running from a debugger

Comment: Thanks, obvisouly that was the reason. Changing another data access library clealy solved this issue.